# Is there any way for making mat-sort to work for complex json?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I have a complex JSON like this:

```
"questionList": [
   {
      "questionCategory": {
         "questionCategoryName": "Web"
      },
      "section": {
         "marksPerQuestion": 2
      },
      "questionText": "Which is true ?"
   },
   {
      "questionCategory": {
         "questionCategoryName": "Mathematics"
      },
      "section": {
         "marksPerQuestion": 1
      },
      "questionText": "What is the value of 2+2 ?"
   }
]
```

I have populated this in Mat-Table also used Mat-Sort to sort the columns but here I am facing the problem. The problem is occurring for `questionCategoryName` and `marksPerQuestion`. `questionText` is sorting perfectly. What I am seeing is that simple keys are sorting perfectly but not the other ones. My typescript code for this JSON is:

**TS**

```
columnsToDisplay: string[];
getTableData() {
  this.columnsToDisplay = ['questionCategory', 'questionText', 'section'];
  this.adminService.getQuestion().subscribe(response => {
    this.QuestionData = response.questionList;
    this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<any>(this.QuestionData);
    this.length = this.QuestionData.length;
    this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
    this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
    this.isLoading = false;
  });
}
```

**HTML**

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort multiTemplateDataRows>
  <ng-container matColumnDef="{{column}}" *ngFor="let column of columnsToDisplay">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>
      {{
        column=='questionCategory'?'Question Category':column=='questionText'?'Question':
        column=='section'?'Mark(s)':''
      }}
    </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
      {{
        column=='questionCategory' ? element[column].questionCategoryName : column=='isActive' ?
        element[column] ? 'Active' : 'Inactive' : column=='section' ? element[column].marksPerQuestion :
        element[column]
      }}
    </td>
  </ng-container>
</table>
```

This is my table. What is the problem mainly I am facing?

This is the [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-rjn6st?file=src/app/app.component.ts) example I have made.

Comment: can you please implement the logic with respect to your suggestion in my Stackblitz link ?

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackoverflow-63486379?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: thanks.. this is what I wanted

Comment: also 1 more thing for filter is there anything similar to this ?

Comment: I suggest you to look first to API documentation : https://material.angular.io/components/table/api#MatTableDataSource if you face any issue implementing your code you can ask a new question :)

Comment: @ibenjelloun 1 thing I just noticed is that while sorting 'Av' comes before 'Ar'. Is angular sorting with respect to length? If yes any solution of making it work alphabetically.
Example: 'Avishek', 'Arunavod'